# NSFetchRequest based on array property size

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a `NSManagedObject` which has a (transformable) `NSArray` property `arrayProperty`.

I would like to execute a fetch request filtering for objects whose property size is less than 5. I tried

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"arrayProperty.@count <= 5"]
```

and

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"arrayProperty[SIZE] <= 5"]
```

but none of them work (giving `Unsupported function expression count` and `Unsupported function [SIZE]`).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Not if you are fetching from a SQLite store: the transformable is stored as a blob - CoreData cannot convert your predicate into a SQL where clause that can analyse the blob.  Either fetch everything and filter in memory, or review whether your array should in fact be modelled as a to-many relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of thing isn't possible with transformable properties. Transformable are convenient for storing data, but once they're stored, that's all they are-- a bunch of bytes with no information about the data structure that created them. SQLite doesn't know that it's an array, so it's not able to do things like count how many items are in the array.

If you use transformable properties, you lose any ability to filter based on them, except for extremely basic tests like whether the value is nil.

If you need to do this kind of filtering, you'll need to consider how to change your data model. One possibility would be that instead of saving an array, create a new entity with a to-many relationship to store the values.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was thinking but could not find it stated anywhere. Will add a NSNumber* arrayCount to my model...